# Inverse of functions of a Random Variable

Tags: probability, functions, random-variables

Given a function of a random variable, I think I understand how to find the corresponding PDF. However, I am trying to understand the inverse. This problem illustrates what I mean:

> The random variable X is uniform in the interval $(-1,1)$. Find $g(x)$ such that if $Y = g(x)$, then $f_y(y) = 2e^{-2y}*U(y)$

I believe $U(y)$ is the Unit Step Function
I believe I am supposed to take advantage of the fact that there is uniform distribution present (that is integrate the PDF we have given in the problem over the interval $(-1,1)$), but I'm not quite sure where to even start or how to solve this problem. Much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Find the cumulative density function for $y$.

It is called $F_y(y)$ and is defined as $F_y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^y f_y(t) dt$.

In your case you can use $F_y(y)=\int_{0}^y f_y(t) dt$ because $f_y(t)=0$ for $t\le 0$.

Also find the cumulative density function for $x$.

It is called $F_x(x)$ and is defined as $F_x(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_x(t) dt$.

In your case you can use $F_x(x)=\int_{-1}^x f_x(t) dt$ because $f_x(t)=0$ for $t\le -1$. I assume you know $f_x(x)$ for the uniform distribution.

Once you have $F_x(x)$ and $F_y(y)$ you can proceed:

If $Y=g(X)$ then $F_x(x)=F_y \left (g(x) \right)$

Thus $F_y^{-1} \left (F_x(x) \right )=g(x) $

You should get $F_x(x)=\frac {x+1}2$

and $F_y(y)=1-e^{-2y}$

So $\frac x2 + \frac 12 = 1-e^{-2g(x)}$

$e^{-2g(x)} =\frac 12 - \frac x2$

$-2g(x) =\ln \left ( \frac 12 - \frac x2 \right )$

$g(x) =-\frac 12 \ln \left ( \frac 12 - \frac x2 \right )$

Comment: When you say $f_x(t)$ for the uniform distribution do you mean $\frac{1}{b-a}$?

Comment: @BillyThorton Yes, I do.

Comment: In this case, what would be the best way to approach integrating $f_y(t) dt$ as you said earlier with the unit step function? Integration by parts?

Comment: The effect of the unit step function is simply to "switch off" the chance of the variable taking values less than zero. So you have $f_y(t)=0$ for $t <0$ and $f_y(t)=2e^{-2t}$ for $t \ge 0$. Nothing fancy to integrate.

Comment: Also, why is $F_x(x)$ not found by integrating from $(-1,1)$ instead of $(-1,x)$?

Comment: If you integrate between $-1$ and $1$ you will just get the value $1$. By integrating between $-1$ and $x$ you get a function in terms of $x$ that increases from $0$ to $1$ as you reach the upper bound. That's the property that cumulative distribution functions have.